# Help with EntityQuery Loading

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, domainservices

I have the following code:

```
        EntityQuery<Web.Ticket> query =
               from t in ticketClass.getQuery()
               where t.showId == selectedShowId
               select t;

        LoadOperation<Web.Ticket> loadTic = ticketClass.loadTicketsQuery(query);
        loadTic.Completed += (s, a) =>
        {
            List<int> takenSeats = new List<int>();
            foreach (Web.Ticket ticket in ticketClass.getContext())
            {
                takenSeats.Add((int)ticket.seatId);
                MessageBox.Show(ticket.seatId.ToString());
            }
        };
```

getQuery:

```
public EntityQuery<Web.Ticket> getQuery()
        {
            return _ticketContext.GetTicketsQuery();
        }
```

loadTicketsQuery:

```
public LoadOperation<Web.Ticket> loadTicketsQuery(EntityQuery<Web.Ticket> query)
        {
            return _ticketContext.Load(query);
        }
```

getContext:

```
public EntitySet getContext()
        {
            return _ticketContext.Tickets;
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that the MessageBox does not load, I have made sure there are two pieces of data that should be caught it never gets there. Can anyone help me on why my code isn't working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
loadTic.Completed += (s, a) =>
    {
        List<int> takenSeats = new List<int>();
        foreach (Web.Ticket ticket in  ((LoadOperation<Web.Ticket>)s).Entities.ToList())
        {
            takenSeats.Add((int)ticket.seatId);
            MessageBox.Show(ticket.seatId.ToString());
        }
    };
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' to type 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation`1[Repas.Web.Ticket]'. -- I am using a button event handler with this code

Comment: @Sandeep I changed `sender` to `s` which is the parameter in from the lambda expression.

Comment: That doesn't work either, I put a breakpoint before the LoadOperation<>.. and it breaks, but after nothing gets executed in the loop

Comment: try doing `MessageBox.Show( ((LoadOperation<Web.Ticket>)s).Entities.Count() );` before the for-loop. if it returns zero then the query is not returning anything.